# Shiny reactive UI not running server code

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to get a Shiny reactive UI running. It is getting quite complex (in terms of lines of code) so I thought refactoring was a good idea. To put it short, this is my server code:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(h2o)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  #stop()
  localH2o <<- h2o.init(nthreads = 3) #Global variable

  source("BuilderServer.R", local = TRUE)[1]
  source("ReviewerServer.R", local = TRUE)[1]

  # CleanupFUnctions
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    rm(list=ls())
  }) 
})
```

where I assumed `source` with `local = TRUE` was just like copy-paste the content of the R files. So they contain functions of the form `output$functionName <- renderUI({code})`. The ui code depends on these functions, most of them are reactive, the ui code looks like this:

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Metamodel",
  tabPanel("Build Custom Model",
    fluidRow(
      column(12,align="center",
        uiOutput("BuilderUpTitle")
      )
    ),  
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
          uiOutput("BuilderAxisSelector")
      )
    )
  )
))
```

In this particular case, the `"BuilderUpTitle"` function looks like this:

```
output$BuilderUpTitle <- renderUI({
  inFile <- input$BuilderInputFile
  if(is.null(input$BuilderInputFile)){
    fileInput("BuilderInputFile", "Upload a xlsx file")
  } else {
    #R Stuff done here with the file
    textInput("text", label = h3("Model Title"), value = "Enter text...")
  }
})
```

I wrote the code yesterday and it was working. Today I turned on the computer again, and when launching the app, not even the dependencies from the server.R appear to load (ggplot2 and h2o). The download button from the `"BuilderUpTitle"` function doesn't appear at all and shiny appears to only execute the ui.R code. I set the workspace to the folder of the sourcefiles and it doesn't help. Even if I uncomment the `stop()` function from the server, nothing seems to change. Setting breakpoints in RStudio doesn't stop the code inside the server, so that is why I think shiny is not calling the server function. However, the code was working before and I did not modify a single file. I even copied the content of the source files to the server.R code and still they do not load. Is there something obvious that I'm missing? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, once again, I found myself what the problem is, and none of the things I said would've made anyone find what was wrong. Here is the tiniest possible code that reproduces the problem:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("itWillLock"),
    uiOutput("itWillLock")
  )
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$itWillLock <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("slider","Slider",min=0,max=1,value=0)
  })
})
```

I guess R gets stuck in an infinite loop and never reaches the server.R file. Is this a bug that I should report? Or just common sense will keep people out of this trouble. Thank you!

Comment: Its not an infinite loop. ui.r Can't have multiple references to the same output-bound object.